# Why does my INDEX-MATCH formula in Excel return 0 as the result?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following in an Excel file:

- In the first sheet, named "Master" there is a table with 2 columns.
- Column A is called "Names" and have a list of names
- Column B is called "Points"

In the second sheet, called "Points" there is also a table.
Column A is called "Names" and have the same list of names as the first sheet
Subsequent columns are named after specific dates and contains points.

I want to display in the first sheet, column "Points" the latest points added in the second sheet for a certain name. In this way, in the "Master" sheet, I can always have the latest available data.

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

I tried the following formula:
`=INDEX(Points!$B:$Z, MATCH(A2, Points!$A:$A, 0), MAX(IF(Points!$A$1:$Z$1<>"", COLUMN(Points!$A$1:$Z$1)-COLUMN(Points!$A$1)+1)))`

Since I want to keep adding columns with data in the second sheet, I figured that I would extend the range until the column "Z" for future proofing.

The results are always 0

Any takers?

Thanks!
Arky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indexed range started at column B, where it works if you change it to start at A.

However I recommend using Table references if you use them.

In this case, since your Master and Points tables have the names in the same row, you could accomplish this by:

`=INDEX(Table2[#All],ROW([@Names]),COLUMNS(Table2))`
(where Table2 is the name of the table in sheet `Points'):
[image]

Otherwise you need to INDEX that and use match:
`=INDEX(INDEX(Table2,,COLUMNS(Table2)),MATCH([@Names],Table2[Names],0))`

In Office 365:
`=@TAKE(Table2,,-1)` in case of same order,
or `=INDEX(TAKE(Table2,,-1),XMATCH([@Names],Table2[Names]))` if mixed.
[image]

Alternately you may want to skip using a table for your results at all and use the following (in Office 365):

`=CHOOSECOLS(Table2,1,COLUMNS(Table2))`
[image]

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer!
Unfortunately this messes with the sorting no? 
I just tried and it retrieves the data correctly, but when sorting the columns, the data gets jumbled.
Thanks again!

Comment: Which version did you use? do you have Office 365?

Comment: `=INDEX(INDEX(Table2,,COLUMNS(Table2)),MATCH([@Names],Table2[Names],0))` should work in any version and no matter where your tables are positioned. You may have a different named table and need to reference that table name.

Comment: I'm an idiot and had a formula set in the Names column of the second sheet. Your solution works perfectly for me.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use `MATCH()` function. By matching `MAX(dates)` you can detect latest column for points. Try-

```
=INDEX($F$2:$I$5,MATCH(A2,$E$2:$E$5,0),MATCH(MAX($F$1:$I$1),$F$1:$I$1,0))
```

[image]

Incase to refer `Sheet2`, use-

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$B$2:$E$5,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$5,0),MATCH(MAX(Sheet2!$B$1:$E$1),Sheet2!$B$1:$E$1,0))
```

Comment: Because the user uses Tables the dates (headers) are converted into text and MAX will not work on text).

Comment: @P.b But it is strongly recommended to use actual date then use desired format.

Comment: A table will convert the header values to text (use ctrl-T on your data and check what happens)

Comment: check this for illustration: https://streamable.com/7erdd3